# How get function parameters size in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I created the function with parameter varchar(1) I want get this parameter size.

I tried read this information from **information_schema.system_views.parameters** but failed, I didn't find the answer in this view. Can I read parameter size from metadata table in redshift?